# Gstat prediciton with heterogenous measurement errors

Tags: r, kriging, gstat

I have a set of measurements for a variable Z over a non uniform grid in X and Y. For each Z value I have a mean plus a variance of the measurement. That is, I have a data set (Zmean_i,Zvariance_i,X_i,Y_i) i=1..N. In other words, some estimates of the variable Z are more reliable than others, and that uncertainty is quantified in Zvariance. If I only take into account the mean Z value the process for predicting the Z values on a new data Grid (GridXY) is clear (SP is the spatial data frame with X and Y as coordinates and Zmean as values)

v <- autofitVariogram(Zmean~X+Y,SP)
Zpredicted <- krige(Zmean~X+Y,SP,GridXY,model=v$var_model)

When using the gstat package, How would I take into account the variance of each Z value (Zvariance) both in fitting the variogram model and also in making predicitions?

Answer (score 0):

The `autofitVariogram` does not have the argument to include measurement error. The best solution is to write the kriging equations in R by yourself.

Alternatively, you can use the `DiceKriging` R package which has the argument to include measurement error. See the argument `noisy.var` in the `km` function. You could also look at the `krige0` function and modify its internal structure by adding manually the measurement error to the diagonal of the covariance matrix.

For the theory, see the paper of [Delhomme (1978)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0309170878900398) or the Geostatistics book of Chiles and Delfiner.